Flutter App crashes on Adding google_sign_in dependency
I just wanted to add google sign in functionality via firebase in my flutter app (project) but everytime I add google_sign_in dependency in my flutter project. The app doesn't run and fails with an error message. But when I remove this dependency it just works fine. I really want to add this feature in my app but unable to whenever I try, I happens all the time even in new project.
Error message -
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':google_sign_in_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\huzai\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\huzai\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\huzai\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

Here are my project configuration -
Java Version installed -  Java_17
Flutter version - 3.24.4
android/app/build.gradle file -
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.letsmeetz"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.letsmeetz"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

android/build.gradle -
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Dependencies in pubspec.yaml -
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  firebase_core: ^3.6.0
  cloud_firestore: ^5.4.4
  firebase_auth: ^5.3.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1

And I have tried both before and after setting up connection to firebase, in both cases the build fails.
And I am new to flutter project building like configuring buildscript and all so please mention comprehensively if you can. I would love to get any help on anything !
And also mention If I need to further mention something.
I tried all the things and followed all the things chatGpt suggested.
Tried clean and rebuild flutter project, clearing cache multiple times -
flutter clean
flutter pub get ,etc
and even installed and tried multiple jdk 17, 20, 21.

You can find the solution in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79068663

Update the com.android.application plugin to version 8.3.2 in the android/settings.gradle file

setting the distributionUrl to version 8.5 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file


